# children line number android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, seekbar

I wanna to do line number for children app 
The line should look like the following 
[image]
I think to use seekbar but I found it not possible as a range, not static also need to do an action when the user touches each number. so I ask for help or suggestion.

also has to do functionality of drawing an arc 
[image]

the arc has to be drawn dynamically while the user moves his finger on numbers

also draw a rectangle when touching any number.
I'd like to ask for any advice or help in implementing something like that.


**edit1**: the line used to solve an equation as in the third image 
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar , https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar

Comment: You can get idea from these libraries.

Comment: thank you @Khemraj but it didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom View (Custom Drawing) which can help you in drawing the shaps check the link hope it helps[custom-views android-developers](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)

Comment: I'm trying to do that bro, but I face some difficulties doing that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a much better way to do this but here's what I came up with, hope its enough to point you in the right direction:

Activity:

```
public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    float startPointX = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

        MyDrawable drawing = new MyDrawable(this);
        setContentView(drawing);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        MyDrawable drawing = new MyDrawable(this);

        if (event.getY() > 1000) {  // Click below line to reset
            startPointX = 0;
        } else if (startPointX == 0) {  // Draw rectangle
            startPointX = event.getX();
            drawing = new MyDrawable(this, startPointX);
        } else if (startPointX > 0) {   // Draw arc
            drawing = new MyDrawable(this, startPointX, event.getX());
        }

        setContentView(drawing);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Drawable:

```
public class MyDrawable extends View {
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint mRedPaint;
    private Paint mGreenPaint;
    private Paint mBluePaint;

    float baseLine = 500;
    float rectangleX;
    float arcEnd;

    public MyDrawable(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDrawable(Context context, float startPoint) {
        super(context);

        rectangleX = startPoint;
    }

    public MyDrawable(Context context, float startPoint, float endPoint) {
        super(context);

        rectangleX = startPoint;
        arcEnd = endPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mCanvas = canvas;

        int width = 1000;

        setupPaint();

        canvas.drawLine(50, baseLine, width, baseLine, mBluePaint);

        int mark = 50;
        while(mark < width) {
            canvas.drawLine(mark, baseLine-50, mark, baseLine+50, mGreenPaint);
            mark += (width /10);
        }

        drawRectangle();
        drawArc();
    }

    private void setupPaint() {
        mRedPaint = new Paint();
        mRedPaint.setARGB(255, 180, 0, 0);
        mRedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRedPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);

        mGreenPaint = new Paint();
        mGreenPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 180, 0);
        mGreenPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);

        mBluePaint = new Paint();
        mBluePaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 180);
        mBluePaint.setStrokeWidth(30);

    }

    public void drawRectangle() {
        if ( rectangleX > 0) {
            mCanvas.drawRect(rectangleX - 25, baseLine-50, rectangleX + 25, baseLine+50, mRedPaint);
        }
    }

    public void drawArc() {
        if (arcEnd != 0 && arcEnd < rectangleX) {
            mCanvas.drawArc(arcEnd, baseLine-200, rectangleX, baseLine, 0, -180, false, mRedPaint);
        } else if (arcEnd != 0 && arcEnd > rectangleX) {
            mCanvas.drawArc(rectangleX, baseLine-200, arcEnd, baseLine, 0, -180, false, mRedPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but my start for arc not always first or end it is changeable also same for drawing the rectangle